# Android. Recycler view with mutiple view types

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView with 2 view types (item and FOOTER). I need to show my footer on the bottom of screen even if no items or items size is 1. Is it possible to implement it? Now my footer is showing after last item, but I need show footer always on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure that allows you to do so, and then you need the view holders for supporting it, once that is done handling the conditional flows on the adapter and should be good to go.

Usually, in Kotlin we use a `sealed class` which allows very good type control

```
sealed class AdapterRow {
    data class RegularItem(/*your values*/) : AdapterRow()
    data class FooterItem(/*your values*/) : AdapterRow()
    //if the footer is always the same maybe object FooterItem : AdapterRow() is more suitable

}
```

It's a nice "trick" to have the sealed descendants inside so that way the sealed parent makes a domain space name, then you call them like this `AdapterRow.RegularItem(...)`. If you don't like that, the sealed class has one constraint, descendants must be on the same file.

Then you need a view holder for supporting each type (view holder and the view in the layout if needed). In this case we are gonna use an abstract class to take advantage of the polymorphism and abstract methods

```
//you could use binding here and then the implementation define the binding type
abstract class BaseViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) { 
    abstract fun bind(row: AdapterRow)
}
```

And then the children:

```
class RegularItemViewHolder(view: View) : BaseViewHolder(view) {

    override fun bind(row: AdapterRow) {
         //validate the data you are receiving is correct
         if (row !is AdapterRow.RegularItem) return
         //do your data bindings, view findings or whatever
    }

}
```

With the above you can deduce the other view holder, now the adapter methods

```
getItemViewType(position: Int) {
    when(getItem(position)) {
        is AdapterRow.RegularItem -> R.layout.REGULAR_ITEM_LAYOUT
        is AdapterRow. FooterItem -> R.layout.FOOTER_ITEM_LAYOUT
    }

}

onCreateViewHolder(...) {
    return when (viewType) {
         R.layout.REGULAR_ITEM_LAYOUT -> {
             RegularItemViewHolder(...)
         }
         R.layout.FOOTER_ITEM_LAYOUT {
             //same but for footer
         }
         else -> throw RuntimeException("Unsupported view Holder)
    }

}

onBindViewHolder(...) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position))
}
```

The data construction part is the last thing, in somewhere else, your fragment, the view model, etc, you have to create the data structure as you need. By example:

```
fun makeRows(texts: List<String>): List<AdapterRow> {
    val rows = mutableListOf<AdapterRow>()
    texts.forEach { text ->
        //do some mapping from what ever is your source in this case strings
        AdapterRow.RegularItem(...text)
    }
    //so it doesn't matter if the source of data is empty at the end you always add the footer
    rows.add(AdapterRow.FooterItem)
}
```

And then is just passing the data to the adapter, if you are using `ListAdapter`

```
val rows = someClass.makeRows(....)
yourAdapter.submitList(rows)
```